# Multiple module.exports

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have this code here

`var router = require('./Router/index')(app, passport);`

Im passing app and passport to my index.js file

```
module.exports = function (app,passport) {
  // App's API
  app.use('/api', require('./Routes/AppRoute'));
  // Website
  app.use('/', require('./Routes/Website'));
  app.use('/keys', require('./Routes/KeysRoute'));
  app.use('/users', require('./Routes/UsersRoute'));
};
```

Im going to use passport in my website route file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Users = require('../../Class/Users');

router.get('/CreateUser', function (req, res) {
  Users.getUsers(function(result){
    res.render('NewUser');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can i pass the passport object over to be used in my website route file?

Comment: Take a look at `node_modules/` folder, im sure some libs doing exact what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern further of exporting a function. Though, instead of exporting the `router`, the function can `return` it.

```
var express = require('express');
var Users = require('../../Class/Users');

module.exports = function (passport) {
  var router = express.Router();

  // ...

  return router;
};
```

Then, invoking the exported function to pass along `passport` from `index.js`:

```
module.exports = function (app,passport) {
  // App's API
  app.use('/api', require('./Routes/AppRoute')(passport));
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function (app,passport) {
  // App's API
  app.use('/api', require('./Routes/AppRoute'));
  // Website
  app.use('/', require('./Routes/Website')(passport));
  app.use('/keys', require('./Routes/KeysRoute'));
  app.use('/users', require('./Routes/UsersRoute'));
};
```

You Website route file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Users = require('../../Class/Users');

module.exports = function (passport) {

    router.get('/CreateUser', function (req, res) {
      Users.getUsers(function(result){
        res.render('NewUser');
      });
    });

}
```